# Can I change specific part of data in cookie

Tags: json, cookies

I just want to know that suppose I am storing a jQgrid's data such as sorted column name, sort order and page no. in cookie in the format of JSON string, So in that can I change only specific data in that JSON string such as page no.. is it possible....??

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, it is possible. You can simply read the JSON string, call `$.parseJSON(string)` to get it back as an object, change the property you want and save it again with `JSON.stringify(object);`

Comment: Ok.. but if i want to upadate only page no without retrieving whole JSON string from cookie..then it is possible???

Comment: Well, yes, simply overwrite the previous value with the new value but you can't update just part of the value, you have to replace the *whole* string. What's the issue with retrieving the whole string, and then replacing it?

Comment: Issue is performance. In my ASP.NET project i am using jQgrid and there are around 20 grids in project and all grid's specific data i am planning to store in cookie that's why I asked you... anyways thanx a lot to guiding me and to clear my doubt... keep supporting.. thanx again...

Comment: @Rahul Why don't you measure how much time it takes to replace 20 values in 20 cookies. I really doubt that it would take longer than a couple milliseconds. Instead, unless you need to retrieve the cookie values on the server-side, I would use localStorage (it's even supported since IE8+!) instead of cookies since they travel with every request. But again, you have to determine whether that would work for you or not or what kind of browsers you need to support...